# Insulate Exterior Breaker Panel

Tags: electrical-panel, insulation

I live in Las Vegas, NV. Our home builder installed our breaker panel on the (out)side of the house that gets full, direct sun for 8 hours of the day. After 5 years in this house, the direct summer sun was too much for the breaker switch for the subpanel. It tripped and couldn't be reset until the weather cooled down. (It recently rained here.) We were without power to all our inside outlets and switches for 2 weeks. The builder agreed to replace the switch; their electrician said this could happen to the main breaker too. (This would cause an emergency issue cause that's for our air conditioning units.) Only if our builder had enough foresight to build our house flipped so the panel could have been on the other side... like our neighbors is. I would like to prevent this from happening again. Is there something that can be installed to protect the panel? Some kind of shade or insulation? Thank you. [Our panel](https://app.box.com/s/hhvm0svwcufcwbjox36j9whigdqo8vyn)

Comment: An awning should be okay.  It will shade the panel and allow wind/air movement to cool a bit.  Awnings over the windows will also help with cooling/stop excess heat in the house.

Comment: An awning. This would definitely have to be approved by our HOA. How would something like that hold up to our occasional 50mph winds we get here?

Comment: Your local power company might help.  The box/panel might be yours, but the meter is the power company's property.  Excess heat does not do the meter any good either, so they might persuade the HOA into having a sun shade/awning.  It does not hurt to ask.

Comment: A **fence** of suitable height and location (needs to be 3 feet away from the front of the panel for working clearances) could also work. Somehow I can't see a lot of hope for most **shade trees** there, but perhaps a **mesquite**?

Answer (score 3):

You could build or have built a meter enclosure similar to the one shown below from Fine Homebuilding. We have a lot of them down here in South Florida. The HOA usually don't have any problems with them because they are a big improvement over the exposed meter centers. The doors aren't locked so the power companies don't care.
https://www.finehomebuilding.com/2002/07/01/electric-meter-covers

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into that.